# Docker-swarm across multiple hosts using same docker-compse file

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-stack

I am building a docker swarm across 3 hosts for the following services, Grakn, Redis, Elasticsearch, MinIO and RabbitMQ.

My queries are this,

1. Can i use one docker-compose.yml so that everything builds across 3 hosts? Or we need to have 3 docker-compose.yml file?
2. In order to have HA, I also want to build 3 more host so that say, if one host (physical) fails, the services which are running on this be transfered to other one and service wont be interrupted.
3. Can i use docker stack here, if so how?

```
services:
  grakn:
    image: graknlabs/grakn:1.7.2
    ports:
      - 48555:48555
    volumes:
      - grakndata:/grakn-core-all-linux/server/db
    restart: always
  redis:
    image: redis:6.0.5
    restart: always
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.8.0
    volumes:
      - esdata:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
    restart: always
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536
  minio:
    image: minio/minio:RELEASE.2020-05-16T01-33-21Z
    volumes:
      - s3data:/data
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    environment:
      MINIO_ACCESS_KEY: ${MINIO_ACCESS_KEY}
      MINIO_SECRET_KEY: ${MINIO_SECRET_KEY}
    command: server /data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:9000/minio/health/live"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 20s
      retries: 3
    restart: always
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.8-management
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER}
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS}
    restart: always
```

Answer (score 1):

> Can i use one docker-compose.yml so that everything builds across 3
> hosts? Or we need to have 3 docker-compose.yml file?

Yes, you should use one `docker-compose.yml` file. There you declare services and their desired state including number of replicas.

> In order to have HA, I also want to build 3 more host so that say, if
> one host (physical) fails, the services which are running on this be
> transfered to other one and service wont be interrupted.

If you [initialized a cluster of Docker Engines in swarm mode](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-tutorial/) and these engines run on different hosts, service replicas can run on any host. (unless you restrict service placement using [Docker labels](https://docs.docker.com/config/labels-custom-metadata/))

> Can i use docker stack here, if so how?

Yes, run `docker stack deploy --compose-file [Path to a Compose file]`

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. The challenge for me is, I want to run elasticsearch and Grakn services on a dedicated host but need to be part of the Swarm cluster. Do you have any examples or something, how can i configure that.?

Comment: i would search the internet, please, post them in a separate question if you have issues and send me the link, i'll check. if my answer helped, please mark as accepted and upvote